# JSON decoding doesn't work

Tags: json, swift

I want to use and parse a list of radios from CuteRadioAPI
http://marxoft.co.uk/doc/cuteradio-api/stations/

The result from the GET request is something like this :
http://marxoft.co.uk/api/cuteradio/stations?limit=2&sort=title&sortDescending=false&approved=1&offset=50%22}

Seems it's not really a JSON structure...

I tried to decode it like this :

```
struct Radio:Codable {
    var approved: Bool?
    var country: String?
    var creatorId: Int?
    var description: String?
    var genre: String?
    var id: Int?
    var language: String?
    var lastPlayed: String?
    var playCount: Int?
    var source: String?
    var title: String?
}

struct CuteRadioReturn:Codable {
    var Radios : [Radio]
}


let url = URL(string: "http://marxoft.co.uk/api/cuteradio/stations")

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil else {
            self.showAlert(title: "Erreur réseau", message: "\(error!.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            self.showAlert(title: "Erreur données", message: "Liste des radios non disponible !")
            return
        }

        do {
            print ("try")

            guard let radios = try? JSONDecoder().decode(CuteRadioReturn.self, from: data) else {
                print("Error: Couldn't decode JSON")
                return
            }

        }

        print (radios.Radios.count)

}
task.resume()
```

I always get nil in radios...

Any idea to help ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To use Codable with json Any dictionary convert to  struct or class

In Json `{}` is dictionary and `[]`  is Array

according to this your model will be

**Model:**

```
import Foundation

struct CuteRadioReturn: Codable {
    let items: [Radio]
    let next: String
}

struct Radio: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title, description, genre, country: String
    let language, source: String
    let playCount: Int
    let lastPlayed: String
    let creatorID: Int
    let approved: Bool

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, title, description, genre, country, language, source, playCount, lastPlayed
        case creatorID = "creatorId"
        case approved
    }
}

// MARK: Convenience initializers

extension CuteRadioReturn {
    init(data: Data) throws {
        self = try JSONDecoder().decode(CuteRadioReturn.self, from: data)
    }
}
```

**And API Call**

```
let url = URL(string: "http://marxoft.co.uk/api/cuteradio/stations")

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { data, response, error in
            guard error == nil else {
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else {
                return
            }

            if let cuteRadioReturn = try? CuteRadioReturn.init(data: data){
                print(cuteRadioReturn.items)
            }


        }
        task.resume()
```

Answer (score 0):

The response is a dictionary not array and it's main key is **items** Change this to

```
struct CuteRadioReturn:Codable {
  var items : [Radio]
  var next:String
}
```

Comment: Thanks : I tried it but the guard decoder error is fired :
"Error: Couldn't decode JSON"

Comment: in documentation there is a previous but in response there isn't so try to remove it